# Can't get ActiveAdmin Addons nested_select to give a pulldown menu, instead i get checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2, activeadmin, add-on

I am a newbie so excuse any mistakes in format. I am using ActiveAdmin to build an admin section on my website where teachers can take attendance and make assignments and check students work in our nonprofit. I installed ActiveAdmin_Addons to help with nested resources and datepickers. Neither are working like they are supposed to. I want to select the cohort, then select the student, then select if they are present or absent or tardy. I want to use datepicker to be able to select the class_date.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpIn8.png)

```
####app/admin/attendances.rd
form do |f|
### Declare here the model's own form fields:
  f.inputs "Rollcall", collection:[true] do
    f.input :attendance_id, as: :nested_select,
               level_1: { attribute: :cohort },
               level_2: { attribute: :users_id },
               level_3: { attribute: :attendance_id }
          ### Declare here the model's own form fields:
    #end
  end
  f.inputs "Class date" do
    f.input :class_date do |c|
      c.input :class_date, :as => :string, :input_html => {:class => 
        "hasDatetimePicker"}
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
end

class Cohort < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :classrooms
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :classrooms, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_uniqueness :genius

 end

class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user#, required: false
end
```

Comment: Which version of ActiveAdmin?

Comment: Hello @PiersC I am using activeadmin (1.2.1), activeadmin_addons (1.4.0), rails (5.2.0.rc2).

Comment: Does this work with activeadmin 1.1.0? It may be that a change is needed to activeadmin_addons to work with the latest version.

Comment: I see activeadmin_addons 1.4.0 is tested against the latest activeadmin on GitHub and Rails 4.2. 
 You may need to try different combinations and open an issue with them on GitHub.

Comment: I have gotten it to work using any version, granted I am a newbie so I am not sure how successful i was. Has it been tested against Rails 5?

Comment: My guess is Rails 5 is probably OK.  I guess the issue is either with Javascript errors or incorrect combination of CSS. Do you see anything using Chrome developer tools? The documentation for Date Time Picker says use `as: :date_time_picker`

Comment: Yes, i tried ':date_time_picker' first. Maybe it is clashing with another add-on? I am not seeing anything that sticks out to me in dev tools.

Comment: You have other addons? I suggest opening an issue on GitHub for ActiveAdminAddons and linking here, perhaps Leandro can help.

Comment: there was a similar unanswered question, i just added my issue to that. https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/issues/201

Comment: @PiersC is there maybe an application helper im missing?

Comment: any updates here?